# Dark Souls II. HP not increased

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have acquired the Ring of Binding, but my HP is still capped at 50%. I tried using a Human Effigy as well, but my HP still goes down to 50% after just a few deaths.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Seems weird, are you sure you aren't cursed? If i remember correctly curse brings your health under 50% and more quickly

Comment: Silly question, but have you equipped the ring?

Comment: yes i got that from box. I checked in my inventory it is there. Also use option is disabled. SO i believed i am using it. Not sure if i have to do something else than this. 

Can you please tell me how to check if i am cursed. Also a way to remove that curse.

Comment: Thankyou :P i have not equipped that. Thought it will be auto used :P.

Comment: Also can you please tell me if ring has specific limits like the weapons as those can be broken or some time limits ?

Comment: Also please refer me to some sites. Where i can check if my basics are complete to play this game. Like i didnot had idea about the rings

Comment: @Jubatus Cursing in Dark Souls 2 works differently from Dark Souls 1. In DkS1, cursing would kill you, and cut your HP to half. Now, in DkS2, all it does is reduce your health down to the minimum cap (and hollow you if you aren't already). If you are wearing the Ring of Binding, that minimum cap is brought up to 75%, rather than 50%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rings cannot be "Used", they must be equipped, like weapons and armour. To do this, you will have to go through the Inventory screen, over to the top left of the screen (there are 4 ring slots) select one of these, and you can choose a ring that will be equipped.

Also, check that the ring isn't broken - this is what it looks like if it is:

[image: Broken rings in player inventory]

If a ring is broken, you will need to visit a [Blacksmith](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Blacksmiths) to get it repaired.

Additionally, if your health has already been reduced below this point, the ring **will not boost your health back up to the minimum cap**. It will only stop your health *falling below* this point, but it will not increase it to match this point.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yup, inventory display with a red box around the items and a prompt to repair for 1250 souls.

Comment: yes i have identified that.

Comment: @MHaseeb can you please be a bit more specific? Identified what? That you have it equipped or that it is/isn't broken?

Comment: i didn't know that rings needs to be equipped. SO i equipped that

Comment: @MHaseeb Ok, thanks for the input. If this answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the "tick" icon to the left of the answer. This will make it easier for other users to find this solution in future :)